# How to load ajax partials on tabs by Angularjs

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, angular-ui

Is it possible to load nested partials with forms inside to the partial tabs such as:

```
<ng-include src="'form_group.html'"></ng-include>
```

Another issue is that the expressions {{}} are not binding to the actual output, am I missing something? I wanted to retain the two-way binding of the expression and scopes of the text partial contents in the Controller.

[Plunkr Source code](http://plnkr.co/edit/SHJhsg?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this

**[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/rX6BDVvtTR9mJSLdA1tG?p=preview)**

```
app.directive('bindHtmlUnsafe', function( $parse, $compile ) {
    return function( $scope, $element, $attrs ) {
        var compile = function( newHTML ) {
            newHTML = $compile(newHTML)($scope);
            $element.html('').append(newHTML);        
        };

        var htmlName = $attrs.bindHtmlUnsafe;

        $scope.$watch(htmlName, function( newHTML ) {
            if(!newHTML) return;
            compile(newHTML);
        });

    };
});
```

Comment: Hi Nidish, thank you for getting the first one fixed, however I'am using a higher version of angular 1.2.8 here is the revised plunker but the directive seem to be wrong (Im not very good at directives) http://plnkr.co/edit/G9DuRp?p=preview

Comment: @YajeDev That you have to put up on another question, since in this SO you asked about expressions {{}}  binding issue

Comment: Okay Nadish understood